# css grid. Расположение внутри контейнера

Tags: css, grid

Нужен такой вид. Как не кручу - не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример, используем `viewport units` - `vh`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid__item {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю.. А зачем тут три колонки?

Comment: т.к это не кол-во колонок, а точки начала и конца для этих колонок, т.е 1 колонка начинается с 1 и заканчивается на 2

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 60vw 40vw 40vw;`

Comment: @Oliver Patterson - обновил ответ